# How long would it take to copy 100GB from one S3 bucket to another in the same region?

Tags: amazon-s3

When I created my bucket 2 years ago, I didn't think about giving it a name good for a CNAME entry, and now I need that feature.

Some files I can move, but others I would rather copy, because I don't want to break third party links that point to the "old" bucket name.

My requirements are:

- Copy files whose name matches a certain pattern from bucket A to B
- Move files whose name matches a certain pattern from bucket A to B
- Minimize time
- Minimize cost

I'm interested to know estimates of the time, because my website would need to be offline during the move (because I don't want new files to be added to bucket A resulting in them being lost.)

I'd also like to know what's the best way to perform this copy/move according to the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [COPY](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) commands available in the S3 API. For the move operation, you can first copy the file and then [DELETE](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html) it.

However I would first try this approach on smaller files. The documentation says:

> A PUT copy operation is the same as performing a GET and then a PUT.

If this results in a download and upload of the file, this will be quite time-consuming.

Comment: Do you know if there's a free or cheap program that will allow me to do that? Ideally, I'd like to copy all files from bucket A to B, and let's say that takes 3 hours. Then take my site offline and copy the new files that were uploaded to bucket A during those 3 hours, so it should only take a few seconds.

Comment: In the AWS Console, you can select items in your S3 bucket, right click and select "Copy", go to a new bucket, right click and select "Paste". To select in a bulk, you can select a first item, hold down the Shift key, and then select the last item.